# How to get twitter users/lookup with multiple ids?

Tags: php, json, twitter

I am trying to download Twitter users details using this

`https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=twitterapi,twitter&include_entities=true`

It is not working in PHP. But when I use `https://api.twitter.com/1/users/lookup.json?screen_name=twitterapi&include_entities=true`

it's working and I got the details of user. How to get details of multiple users in single request using API using PHP ?

Comment: [link](https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json??user_id=XXXXXXX%2CXXXXXXX%2CXXXXXXX)

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution for this `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/lookup.json?user_id=XXXXXXX%2CXXXXXXX%2CXXXXXXX` separate each userids with %2C